# Django Query Filter syntax issue

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.10.5 with python 3.6.

I have the following model classes:

```
class PublishedDetails(FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  ....

class PublishedRecordedActivity(models.Model):
    published_details = models.ForeignKey(PublishedDetails, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    activity_type = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=1)
```

With a lot of assistance, I have a query that will return all the details for the activity type of 1:

```
aggregated_type_1 = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(
activity_type=1).annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp_added')).values(
'month').annotate(sum_by_month=Count('month')).order_by('-timestamp_added')
```

However, I now want to only return the query for specific published details. For example where `published_details=73`, where the 73 is the id value in the model/table `PublisheDetails`.

So I extended the query, but I'm receiving the error: `'publisheddetails__id' is not defined`.

I have imported the models to the view.

Here is the offending query:

```
aggregated_type_1 = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(
activity_type=1, published_details=publisheddetails__id).annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp_added')).values(
'month').annotate(sum_by_month=Count('month')).order_by('-timestamp_added')
```

I have tried back tracking and I have referenced the django docs, but the solution is escaping me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `id` for published_details. In `published_details=publisheddetails__id` the query is actually looking for an `id`, but it got `publisheddetails__id` which is not defined.
Instead, you can try defining a variable and passing it.

```
pub_details_id=73
aggregated_type_1 = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(
activity_type=1, published_details=pub_details_id).annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp_added')).values(
'month').annotate(sum_by_month=Count('month')).order_by('-timestamp_added')
```

Comment: This won't work as I cannot have the filter query hard coded.

Comment: Define a variable then pass the variable instead of the value. `published_details__id=pub_details_id`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
published_details=publisheddetails
```

or:

```
published_details__id=publisheddetails.id
```